# How to do a transaction against two databases

Tags: sql, database, algorithm, transactions, distributed-computing

I have a use-case where I have two different databases -- one local (let's say Postgres) and one remote (let's say MySQL) -- and I need to guarantee that they have the same data. The databases don't matter, this is more a conceptual question. How can I perform what amounts to a 'transaction' across these two databases? In pseudo-code:

```
-- local db
BEGIN TRANSACTION 'local';
UPDATE table SET name='todd' WHERE id=1;

-- remote db
BEGIN TRANSACTION 'remote';
UPDATE table SET name='todd' WHERE id=1;

-- save
COMMIT TRANSACTION 'local';
COMMIT TRANSACTION 'remote'; -- or ROLLBACK
```

The 'second save' is easy -- because we either `ROLLBACK` if the first one failed or `COMMIT` if the first one succeeded. But how would we `ROLLBACK` the first one if for-example the first one succeeded and the second one failed (for whatever reason).

Is there a known algorithm to minimize this risk or properly deal with this?

---

**Update**: where a database supports distributed transactions, this can be done with the `PREPAPRE` keyword -- supported in both [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/xa-states.html) and [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-prepare.html). Having said that, many databases (if not most) databases will not support this, so it'd be interested to see how this might be accomplished across one of those databses as well, for example SQLite being used as the Local DB. Here's also an interesting article about using SQLite for something like this: http://www.scs.stanford.edu/20sp-cs244b/projects/Distributed%20SQLite.pdf.

Comment: No perfect solution exists. See https://cedanet.com.au/antipatterns/distributed-transactions.php for more. But https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol is widely used and in most cases is good enough.